# How do you get the previous/next/done buttons in Mobile Safari date input?

Tags: ios, html, datepicker, mobile-safari

I know I've seen the date picker for iOS with "Previous", "Next" and "Done" buttons before, but for some reason all I'm seeing is the "Clear" button on a standard date input in Mobile Safari. Just wondering if there is a way to enable these other buttons somehow.

Answer (score 1):

According to my testing the Next, Prev and Done buttons appear only on iPhone devices, on iPad there's only Clear button for `<input type="date"></input>` control.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that might be the case... I wonder what the reasoning is for not including them on the iPad. I'm surprised it's not handled the same across all iOS devices.